# Ctrl+c and Ctrl+z to interrupt/suspend jobs

Tags: shell, terminal, signals, interrupt

To kill a hanging job, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, to send an interrupt signal to the hanging job. Sometimes this wouldn't stop the job, at least not immediately.  I can then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to suspend the job and then kill it with `kill %1` (or whatever the number of the job is).

Why is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> more powerful than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in interfering with a job? Sometimes, not even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> works. Are there other key combinations one could use in such situations?

I tried `stty -a`, but none of the other listed key combinations do anything for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (control character `intr`):** It will send `SIGINT` signal to a process and usually application gets abort but the application can handle this signal. For example you can handle a signal with `signal()` function in `C` Language.

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (control character `susp`):** It will send `SIGTSTP` signal to a process to put it in background and like `SIGINT` it can be handle.

The process will not kill immediately with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if it has wait I/O and you have to wait to finish its I/O and then the application will terminate from memory. ‌
But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will pause your process and its I/Os. Technically the operating system will not give it CPU time and if you kill the background process, it may lose some I/O and data.

For force killing a process you have to `SIGKILL` or signal number 9 which is most powerful signal - the operating system will kill it immediately, but you may lose data, as the program will have no way to react to this signal.

Comment: Well, my question is, can I send `SIGKILL` by a key combination when the program does neither respond to `SIGINT` nor to `SIGTSTP`?

Comment: @pdnuesel, you can't do that with shell features but check this link however I think it's not useful: http://superuser.com/questions/288772/shell-sigkill-keybinding